# Eve framework: modify query_string

Tags: python, query-string, webhooks, eve

I'm writing API using Python EVE framework.
In my `on_post_GET` hook I want to extend `request.query_string` with some additional condition for some reason.

This `request.query_string` looks like a raw encoded string and it's not useful to add some new condition into existing.

My string looks like:

`embedded=%7B%22some_key%22%3A1%2C%22another_key%22%3A1%2C%22one_more_key%22%3A1%2C%22and_more_key%22%3A1%2C%22and_more%22%3A1%2C%22some_specific_key%22%3A1%2C%22the_last_key%22%3A1%7D&where=%7B%22some_statement%22%3A%22in%28%5B%5C%22value1%5C%22%2C%5C%22value2%5C%22%5D%29%22%7D&max_results=10&page=1&sort=%5B%28%22date%22%2C0%29%5D`

So, I want to add one additional condition into `WHERE` statement. I may parse it somehow, but there are a few things:

1) I may have another conditions and hardcoding related to condition looks terrible for me.
2) I hope, there is some better way to extend it somehow.

Thoughts?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a `pre_GET` hook to do what you want?

Comment: @gcw, it's a little tricky, because I just need to prepare some allowed data for authenticated user in my `on_fetch` hook, then use this filtered data use in `on_post` hook.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to make your filter by handling the `lookup` inside a `pre_GET` event hook, as in this example from pyeve's [documentation](http://python-eve.org/features.html#dynamic-lookup-filters):

```
def pre_GET(resource, request, lookup):
    # only return documents that have a 'username' field.
    lookup["username"] = {'$exists': True}
app = Eve()

app.on_pre_GET += pre_GET
app.run()
```

Comment: You could even access the `where` contents by calling `request.args.get('where')` inside the hook, but I don't think it is possible to change anything because the args dict is of type ImmutableDict.

Note that the example is for a `pre_GET`, not `post_GET`, so you can still set the lookup filter of your query to the desired values instead of dealing with the `where` param. I think you can set there the same thing that you want in the `where` param.

Comment: `lookup["username"] = {'$exists': True}` this converts into `where={"username": $exists}` in query_string?

Comment: Also, is it possible using this way `lookup["id"] = value` to write query with `IN` clause? I mean something like this: `lookup["id"] = {"$in": [1,2,3]}`

Comment: @smart, yes something like `lookup["_id"] = {"$in": ['579a12a23857e47039afedc', '57a3ec63a9ef130011649237']}` will work. Notice that the default field for ID is `_id`. About `lookup["username"] = {'$exists': True}`, that would be the same as `where={"username": {"$exists": true}}`

Comment: I know about `_id`, but I've monitored my resource and currently it hasn't `_id` field.